# Prove that $\det(kA) = k^n\det(A)$ for all $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I was just looking over an old homework problem, and my proof doesn't seem right. I got full credit for it, but it seems to be circular reasoning. Please tell me if this is actually a valid proof:

Suppose $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$. Then $$\det(kA) = \det(kI_nA) = \det(kI_n)\det(A) = k^n\det(I_n)\det(A) = k^n(1)\det(A) = k^n\det(A).$$

I am wondering if claiming that $\det(kI_n) = k^n\det(I_n)$ was a valid move, since that is basically what the problem asks me to prove. Is it just a given for the identity matrix? I don't remember what I was thinking when originally doing this problem.

(Side note, how do I do a vertically aligned string of equalities in LaTex? )

Comment: The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of its nonzero entries (because there's only one nonzero term in the Lagrange expansion).

Comment: The determinant is row-wise linear. You have $n$ rows. You have one $k$ in each row. So?

Comment: You are doing fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all really depends what your definition of the determinant is, and what lemmas were previously proven.  For example, if your definition is the one with signed permutations,
$$\det(A) = \sum_\pi (-1)^\pi a_{1\pi(1)} \cdots a_{n\pi(n)},$$
then it follows trivially that $\det(kI_n) = k^n$, since there is only one permutation for which the corresponding product of terms does not contain a zero, and that product is of the $n$ diagonal copies of $k$.  (Of course, with this definition it's also obvious straight from the definition that multiplying each entry of $A$ by $k$ multiplies each term of that sum by $k^n$.)

If your definition is by Laplace expansion,
$$\det(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^i a_{i1} \det(A_{i1}),$$
then you require some kind of inductive argument whether or not you factor out $kI_n$ as you did.

If your definition is axiomatic, defining $\det$ to be the unique scalar-valued function on square matrices such that

1. $\det$ is linear in each row of its argument,
2. $\det(A) = 0$ if two rows of $A$ are equal, and
3. $\det(I) = 1$,

then the combination of 1 and 3 implies $\det(kI_n) = k^n$.  On the other hand, just 1 alone implies $\det(kA) = k^n \det(A)$ also.

In other words, your argument may or may not be circular, but I don't think it is actually a simplification.

Comment: Our definition of determinant is by cofactor expansion.

Comment: Do I need to clarify that case, then?

Comment: If you'd be so kind :)

Comment: What else do I need to say?  My opinion is that you can prove either than $\det(kI_n) = k^n$ or that $\det(kA) = k^n \det(A)$ with the same style of induction using Laplace expansion.  It may be that the former identity was proved in class at some point, in which case your proof is not circular.  If it wasn't, then you need to prove it, or else your proof is circular.  I personally feel that you can skip this reduction altogether and just prove the original theorem by induction, but your way works fine, with that additional lemma.

Answer (score 1):

I think the claim that $det(kI_n)=k^ndet(I_n)$ is valid. $kI_n$ looks like the identity matrix but with $k$ in place of each 1 on the main diagonal. Because the determinant of any triangular matrix is the product of the entries on the diagonal, $det(kI_n)$ equals $k$ multiplied by itself $n$ times, i.e. $k^n$. So $det(kI_n)=k^n=k^ndet(I_n)$.